# CLion formatter breaks MOCK_METHOD lines

Tags: c++, formatting, googletest, clion, googlemock

I am using gmock in CLion, whenever I format my file, all the MOCK_METHOD macros are broken up with unnecessary line breaks. like this:

Before:

```
    class MockObservableExecutor : public IObservableExecutor {
        MOCK_METHOD1(registerExecutor, void(IObserverExecutor*));
        MOCK_METHOD2(sendMessage, void(const std::string&, const std::string&));
    };
```

After:

```
    class MockObservableExecutor : public IObservableExecutor {
        MOCK_METHOD1(registerExecutor, void(IObserverExecutor
                *));

        MOCK_METHOD2(sendMessage, void(
                const std::string&, const std::string&));
    };
```

I see no reason that the single asterisk should get a line of its own, how can I tell CLion to stop its shenanigans? Why does it decide that it should break the line there?

For now I have added `//@formatter:off` and `//@formatter:on` statemenst around my mock but I do want formatting to work for some of the stuff in my mock.

Answer (score 1):

That is a bug: [CPP-18644](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-18644) 
It will be fixed in the next EAP/fix-release.
Sorry.